# Wordpress WPForms problem - Emails cannot be delivered

Tags: wordpress, forms, email, contacts

I added contact form on my website and emails flow was ok but as I didn't have any spam protection, I added `WPForms`, turned on captcha and since then, "email cannot be delivered to...." problem exists. I cannot receive mails through contact forms. What could be problem? Is it about setting SMTP? I installed `WP Mail SMTP` plugin but don't know how to configure.

Comment: what is the from email address that you are using? is it your domain based email?

Comment: Yes it is, what can I do now?